# Why/How does this code works in ES6 (React)

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, backticks, styled-components

I'm following a React course and came across this lesson where they import a component from `styled-components` but what is strange to me is line 4 where they use the backticks interpolation without enclosing it in parenthesis and it seems it should not be any space between the backticks and the `styled.header`.

[image]

Comment: `var test = (a) => console.log(a+' man'); test\`whatever\`` will output `whatever man`. In your example, styled.header is a function that receives a string (css, in your example) as its only argument.

Comment: Side-question: what IDE are you using that properly highlights CSS in a string template literal? Does it give you code-completion, too, like `text-align:` suggests `left, right, center` etc? (Lack of that in my IDE was one reason I didn't like styled-components.)

Comment: @Aaron it's language-babel package for Atom, more info here 
https://github.com/styled-components/styled-components#syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's call **Tagged Template Literals**, a new feature in ES6.

You can read more about this in [the styled-components docs](https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#tagged-template-literals) and this [article](https://mxstbr.blog/2016/11/styled-components-magic-explained/).